# Determine the image of the homomorphism

Tags: group-theory

Let $\phi: \mathbb{C}^{\ast} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{\ast}$ be given by $z \mapsto z\bar{z}$, where $\mathbb{C}^{\ast}$ is the group of non-zero complex numbers under multiplication.

I know $z\bar{z}=|z|^{2}$ so would the image be the set of positive real numbers (denoted by $\mathbb{R}^{+}$)?

Comment: You would just check that for a real number $r\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$ either there is any $z\in\mathbb{C}^{*}$ that $|z|^2=r$ or not .

Comment: And how would I know whether there was or not?

Comment: There are not just one number, of course, uncountable such numbers ! For any angle $\theta$ the number $z=re^{i\theta}$ just works

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the image is $\Bbb R^+$. For given $a\in \Bbb R^+$, $\phi(\sqrt{a}) = a$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Pleased that I was right all along!